# sencha touch association

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am trying to get a "has Many" association working using a localstorage. I set up two models : User and Products. My user has many Products. I want to:

Load my user via AJAX from a server after the user is authorized. The Products are already stored in the localstorage (e.g. {"id":"ext-record-1","user_id":1,"name":"product1"}).

```
// The id and name are loaded via ajax
var user = Ext.create('User', {id: 1, name: 'Ed'});
var userProducts = user.products();
userProducts.load();
```

The problem is: All the instances from the store / proxy are loaded if i call the association. According to the docs there should only be the instances with "user_id" : 1

The filter is set. It only happens if i load the products from the localstorage, if i create them in place there is no problem. The saving to a localstore breaks the association.

And i set up an example without a localstorage here:
http://www.senchafiddle.com/#J9VX6

And with the localstorage: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#J9VX6#hBDkq

See http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany

I really appreciate your help

Comment: would be nice if you remove your downvotes or explain why you added them

Comment: The documentation appears to be saying that you do not need to use the line of source "userProducts.load();" because when you use the "var userProducts = user.products();" it will automatically load based on the filter you specified.

Comment: Thank you, but i think this isnt the problem. The problem is using associations with webstorage. See the link in my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as this is a known bug, i got the link on my question in the sencha touch forum:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?173327-WebStorage-proxy-can-t-deal-with-associated-data

I think this will not be solved until the next version of Sencha Touch

Comment: Glad to hear that you now know what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Richard Chambers is right; it shouldn't be necessarily to call load() on the userProducts.

Furthermore. make sure the idProperty on the User model is set to 'id' (that's the default) and the foreignKey on your hasMany association is set to 'user_id'.

If this doesn't provide a solution, you might want to try using a filter on the UserProducts:

```
var userProducts = user.products().filter("user_id", user.id);
```

Comment: I provided an answer, as this seems to be a known problem with webstorage and associations. The load thing wasnt the problem. I am already using a custom filter to workaround the problem. Thank you